# Usage of "keenly aware of"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Need help on right usage of "keenly aware of", what are the similar expressions? Can I say: strongly aware of ?

thanks

Comment: Assuming you want to know what "keenly aware of"  means you need to examine the first word "[keen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keen)": which in this case is used to mean "sharp" (as in a knife's edge).

Comment: You could say "Acutely aware" since "strongly aware" is not commonly seen.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, very helpful. I did some search, found many sample usages of "acutely aware", "fully aware", could not found any "strongly aware"

Comment: Sample usages found: 1.They did it on purpose and fully aware of the consequences.

2. EARLIER this month Brandeis University rescinded its offer of an honorary degree to Ayaan Hirsi Ali, ...., saying its officials had not been fully aware of some her more scathing remarks on Islam.

3. As the founder and former chairman of GMO Europe, ...., Paul Woolley has been keenly aware of inefficiencies, or mispricings, in financial markets.

4. And in his present job he has always been keenly aware of the hard reality that in most international policy debates, all roads lead to Washington.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the words in that phrase are replaceable with others, depending on the context:

*Painfully aware* is one use, denoting an unpleasant awareness of a reality/fact

*Acutely aware* is another (like *Gary's Student* has posited)

*Fully cognizant* could be used in the same vein, replacing *aware* with the word cognizant

The word *mindful* can be used to replace the entire phrase, as (IMO) it adequately conveys a high degree of awareness

Comment: Thanks, seems to me the word aware is rather formal one, not used for informal situations, right?

Answer (score 0):

While 'keen' itself is not, "keenly aware of" insinuates frustration, annoyance, and is defined as 'vigilant'.

If your intent is not to be, less confrontational words are:

cognizant
    [I adjective accomplished, acquainted, alert, apperceptive, apprehensive, apprised, astute, aware, clear-sighted, cognitive, comprehending, conscious, conscius, conversant, discerning, discriminating, educated, endowed with consciousness, endowed with reason, enlightened, erudite, expert, familiar, informed, keen, knowing, knowledgeable, learned, lettered, mindful, perceptive, percipient, perspicacious, possessed of knowledge, posted, practiced, proficient, regardful, sagacious, sage, sensible to, sharp, understanding, versed, well-advised, well-educated, well-grounded, well-informed, well-read, well-versed, wise](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cognizant)

Comment: Wow, so much choices:-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[awake](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awake)," as in:

> The mayor's office is awake (or *fully awake*) to these problems [=The mayor's office is keenly aware of these problems].

Comment: Thanks, wonder if awake is stronger than aware, or they are about the same?