# What is the quality of being concerned or apathetic, worded in a neutral term?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

For example - the quality of "prettiness" and "ugliness" shouldn't be either but "appearance" as one can be pretty or ugly, but not "appearanced".

On the same weight, the quality of "interest" and "apathy" shouldn't be either. It should be a word neutral to both of ends of it's own dichotomy. Concern, curiosity, or interest do not seem to cut it for me.

Comment: There isn't a single word for that category. Instead, English typically uses constructions like _level of interest_.

Comment: ""both ends of it's own dichotomy" sounds like Alice in Wonderland.

Answer (score 2):

After sleeping on this I suggest ***awareness*** as a possibility that is derived from the adjective ***aware***.

At one end of the spectrum we have phrases relating to strong awareness (= ***interest***)  discussed in

> [EnglishStackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/165568/usage-of-keenly-aware-of)
>
> such as:
>
> *keenly aware*, *painfully aware*, *acutely aware*

At the other end we have examples relating to weak awareness (=***apathy*** or *indifference*) such as T S Eliot's

> [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7460362-she-turns-and-looks-a-moment-in-the-glass-hardly)
>
> “She turns and looks a moment in the glass,
>
> Hardly aware of her departed lover ..."

and

> [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2003/08/03/realestate/a-landlord-s-lot-is-sometimes-not-an-easy-one.html)
>
> *So ignorant was I of New York real estate that I was barely aware of the Great Landlord-Tenant War of 1997, which was then raging.*

This neutral range of meanings is reflected in Merriam Webster's account of *awareness*:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awareness)
>
> awareness:
>
> *the quality or state of being aware : knowledge and understanding that something is happening or exists*
>
> *promoting a heightened awareness of the problem*
>
> *seemed to have only a slight awareness of what was going on*
>
> *an acute awareness of subtle differences*
>
> *They hope to raise awareness of endangered species, encouraging donations and attracting tourists to the region to support conservation efforts.* (New Scientist)
>
> *The alternative press played a particularly important role in raising political awareness and facilitating mobilization against the regime in South Africa …* (Larry Diamond)

I also considered *involvement* but it does not seem to match your requirement of wide range and bipolar neutrality so well.

Comment: +1 for both of the terms that you considered. I could only come up with "attitude."